# error creating registry key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.ts\OpenWithProgids. RegCreateKeyEx failed: code 5 Access denied

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, visual-studio-code, windows-authentication

When I open VSCode on Windows 10, I get the following pop-up window message and it requires an action:

```
error creating registry key: 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.ts\OpenWithProgids 
RegCreateKeyEx failed: code 5 
Access denied
```

Why does this happens? What does it mean and how can I get rid of it?

I also checked "run vscode as administrator" on compatibility tab and it asks for "run as administrator" each time I open it, and I grant the access, but still after few seconds the pop-up window appears again.

[image]

Comment: I get the same error, no idea what actually means??